# Html Bootstrap multiple <pre> in one line without spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pre

I need to put three PRE elements in a row without spacing between them using Bootstrap.
I can put them in a row with space with following code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"><pre>*   Red
*   Green
*   Blue</pre></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><pre>+   Red
+   Green
+   Blue</pre></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><pre>-   Red
-   Green
-   Blue</pre></div>
</div>
```

This is what I get:
[image: my screenshot]

I tried to put "no-space" class to div's, to pre's but that didn't help.
Please help! I don't have any ideas how to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the col-classes on the pre tags themselves

```
<div class="row">
<pre class="col-md-4">*   Red
*   Green
*   Blue</pre>
<pre class="col-md-4">+   Red
+   Green
+   Blue</pre>
<pre class="col-md-4">-   Red
-   Green
-   Blue</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to add is this:

```
pre {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```